# Mongo update array subelement using $ operator for multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb

I have following data in my mongo collection:

```
{
    "services" : [ 
        {
            "service" : "service1",
            "instanceId" : 0,
            "attributes" : {
                "attr" : {
                    "value" : "val1"
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "service" : "service1",
            "instanceId" : 1,
            "attributes" : {
                "attr" : {
                    "value" : "val2"
                }
            }
        }, 

    ]
}
```

and I am trying to run following query to update data of instanceid 1, using $ operator:

```
db.device.update({"services.service":"service1", "services.instanceId":1},{"$set":{"services.$.attributes.attr.value":"val3"}},{})
```

But this query always updates instance id 0 of array. I am not able to find any other way to update this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#a-single-nested-document-meets-multiple-query-conditions-on-nested-fields) to target the array element matching on multiple conditions.

Something like

```
db.device.update(
  {"services":{"$elemMatch":{"service":"service1", "instanceId":1}}},
  {"$set":{"services.$.attributes.attr.value":"val3"}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

Try this:

```
db.runCommand({
   update:"sample", //provide collection name here
   updates:[{q:{}, u:{$set:
    {"services.$[element].attributes.attr.value":"val3"}}, arrayFilters: [ { 
     "element.instanceId": 1, "element.service": "service1" } ], multi:true}]  
 })
```

or this:

```
db.sample.update(
 {},
 {$set:{"services.$[element].attributes.attr.value":"val3"}},
 {arrayFilters: [ { "element.instanceId": 1, "element.service": "service1" } 
 ], multi:true}

)
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks to @mickl for the comments and info.

Comment: This will not work, as this will update both the fields, I need to update only specific one.

Comment: So you want to update only instance 1? is that what u mean?

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, but I am not able to run it as we are using mongo 3.4.5, and due to some reason we are not able to upgrade it to newer one. is there any other solution that could be used with version 3.4.5